# Single insert is okay, but bulk import throws error of type "not_x_content_exception"

Tags: elasticsearch, import

I'm trying to import data to Elasticsearch from JSON file which contains one document per line. Only data.

Here is how I'm creating index and trying to insert one document:

`DELETE /tests`

```
PUT /tests
{}
```

```
PUT /tests/test/_mapping
{
  "test":{
    "properties":{
      "env":{"type":"keyword"},
      "uid":{"type":"keyword"},
      "ok":{"type":"boolean"}
    }
  }
}
```

```
POST /tests/test
{"env":"dev", "uid":12346, "ok":true}
```

```
GET /tests/_search
{"query":{"match_all":{}}}
```

Everything works fine, no errors, document is indexed correctly and could be found in ES.

Now let's try to do it using `elasticdump`.

Here is content of file I'm trying to import:

```
cat ./data.json
{"env":"prod","uid":1111,"ok":true}
{"env":"prod","uid":2222,"ok":true}
```

Here is how I'm trying to import:

```
elasticdump \
    --input="./data.json" \
    --output="http://elk:9200" \
    --output-index="tests/test" \
    --debug \
    --limit=10000 \
    --headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}' \
    --type=data
```

But I got error `Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes`.

Here is full output:

```
root@node-tools:/data# elasticdump \
>     --input="./s.json" \
>     --output="http://elk:9200" \
>     --output-index="tests/test" \
>     --debug \
>     --limit=10000 \
>     --headers='{"Content-Type": "application/json"}' \
>     --type=data
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | starting dump
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | got 2 objects from source file (offset: 0)
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT [debug] | discovered elasticsearch output major version: 6
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT [debug] | thisUrl: http://elk:9200/tests/test/_bulk, payload.body: "{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"tests\",\"_type\":\"test\"}}\nundefined\n{\"index\":{\"_index\":\"tests\",\"_type\":\"test\"}}\nundefined\n"
{ _index: 'tests',
  _type: 'test',
  _id: 'ndj4JmoBindjidtNmyKf',
  status: 400,
  error:
   { type: 'mapper_parsing_exception',
     reason: 'failed to parse',
     caused_by:
      { type: 'not_x_content_exception',
        reason:
         'Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes' } } }
{ _index: 'tests',
  _type: 'test',
  _id: 'ntj4JmoBindjidtNmyKf',
  status: 400,
  error:
   { type: 'mapper_parsing_exception',
     reason: 'failed to parse',
     caused_by:
      { type: 'not_x_content_exception',
        reason:
         'Compressor detection can only be called on some xcontent bytes or compressed xcontent bytes' } } }
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | sent 2 objects to destination elasticsearch, wrote 0
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | got 0 objects from source file (offset: 2)
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | Total Writes: 0
Tue, 16 Apr 2019 16:26:28 GMT | dump complete
```

What am I doing wrong? Why manual insert works fine while `_batch` is throwing errors. Any ideas?

**UPD**

Tried using python's `elasticsearch_loader` - works fine.

```
elasticsearch_loader \
    --es-host="http://elk:9200" \
    --index="tests" \
    --type="test" \
    json --json-lines ./data.json
```

Some additional info could be found here: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/issues/534

Comment: May I ask you which Elasticsearch and elasticdump versions do you use?

Comment: @NikolayVasiliev elasticdump = 4.7, ES = 6.5.1 Problem has already been solved by one of elasticdump contributors, see here https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/issues/534

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Json documents should be provided as `_source`.

WAS: `{"env":"prod","uid":1111,"ok":true}`

NOW: `{"_source":{"env":"prod","uid":1111,"ok":true}}`

This could be made on fly by `elasticdump` using `--transform` argument:

```
elasticdump \
    --input="./data.json" \
    --output="http://elk:9200" \
    --output-index="tests/test" \
    --debug \
    --limit=10000 \
    --type=data \
    --transform="doc._source=Object.assign({},doc)"
```

Thanks to @ferronrsmith from github.
More details here: https://github.com/taskrabbit/elasticsearch-dump/issues/534